# How to return None if .index() got ValueError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
date_index = data['date'].index(input_date)
```

From the code above, if input_date not match in any index of data['date'] it will get and error by :

```
> ValueError: '99/99/9999' is not in list
```

but i want to get None when got ValueError.
i have try by use

```
if data['date'].index(input_date) is None:
    return None
else:
    pass
```

but it not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you think the `if` would work? If `.index` returned `None` *you'd already have `None`!* Either `try` and catch the error or check if the item is `in` the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways to handle it:

```
data_index = data['date'].index(date_of_stock) if data['date'] else None
```

Or

```
try:
    data_index=data['date'].index(date_of_stock)
except ValueError:
   data_index=0
```